# Matplotlib text using a condition

Tags: python, loops, matplotlib, seaborn

I have the following dataframe:

```
data = {'Var1':[3,  8,  4,  2, 13],
        'Var2':[5,  7,  9,  10, 15],
        'Name':['obs1', 'obs2', 'obs3', 'obs4', 'obs5']}  
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

And I add labels according to the variable "Name":

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.scatterplot(data=df1,x='Var1',y='Var2')

for i in range(df1.shape[0]):
    plt.text(x=df1.Var1[i]+0.3, y=df1.Var2[i]+0.3,s=df1.Name[i], 
             fontdict=dict(color="black",size=10),
             bbox=dict(facecolor="white",alpha=0.5))
```

Here is the result:

[image: 1]

Now i would like to show the labels under two conditions :
if the observations are above 14 and below 8, then I show the labels.

Do you have a solution ?
Thank you !

Comment: I guess you mean *above 14 **OR** below 8* ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use a simple condition in your loop. Here I skip the loop if 8<Val2<14 using the `continue` keyword:

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.scatterplot(data=df1,x='Var1',y='Var2')

for i in range(df1.shape[0]):
    if 8<df1.Var2[i]<14:
        continue
    plt.text(x=df1.Var1[i]+0.3, y=df1.Var2[i]+0.3,s=df1.Name[i], 
             fontdict=dict(color="black",size=10),
             bbox=dict(facecolor="white",alpha=0.5)
            )
```

output:

[image]

###### alternative code formatting

I take the opportunity to show you a cleaner way for your code (In my opinion):

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.scatterplot(data=df1,x='Var1',y='Var2')

options = dict(fontdict=dict(color="black",size=10),
               bbox=dict(facecolor="white",alpha=0.5))

for i, (x,y,name) in df1.iterrows():
    if y<8 or y>14:
        plt.text(x=x+0.3, y=y+0.3, s=name, **options)
```